# What is the meaning of int *(*papi[10])

Tags: c, pointers

I used cdecl and get its definition as "declare papi as array 10 of pointer to pointer to int"
So I write my code in this way

```
int i = 10;
int *api[10];
api[0] = &i;
int *(*papi[10]);
papi = &api;
```

And I got an error says "array type 'int *(*[10])' is not assignable"

What is the correct way to use the papi?

Comment: Finally totally clear about that, thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I interpretated phrase "declare papi as array 10 of pointer to pointer to int" as declare an array of 10 pointers to pointer to int.:)

Try the following

```
#include < stdio.h>


int main( void )
{
    int i = 10;
    int *api[10] = { &i };
    int **papi[10];
    papi[0] = api;

    printf( "%d\n", ***papi );
}
```

The output is

```
10
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be **papi instead of ***papi?

Comment: @Floyd: `papi` is an array of pointers to pointers to int, `*papi` is a pointer to a pointer to `int`, `**papi` is a pointer to `int`, `***papi` is an `int`.

Comment: Finally understand that, ***papi is equal to **papi[0], thank you for the demo!

Answer (score 4):

Array names are non-modifiable l-values. You can't use them as left operand of `=` operator. `papi` is an array name. Change

```
int *(*papi[10]);
```

to

```
int *(*papi)[10]; // papi is a pointer to an array of 10 pointers to int
```

Comment: Sorry that is a typo and I have fixed that.

Comment: Thank you, I understand int *(*papi)[10], but I thought I was assigning value to the array papi's first location, isn't that?

Comment: @Floyd: That would be `papi[0] = api` (or `papi[0] = &api` if `papi`s declaration was `int *(*papi[10])[10];`). haccks: There's a typo in your second line of code, the trailing `)`.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot assign to an array in C. What you seem to want to do was:

```
int i = 10;
int *api[10];
api[0] = &i;
int *(*papi)[10];
papi = &api;
```

which declares `papi` as a pointer to an array of 10 pointers to `int`. This is the type of `&api`, what takes the address of a 10-element array of pointer to `int`.

HTH

Comment: The difference is that this code compiles without error. +1

Comment: Oh, I understand about this int *(*papi)[10]...., but still not clear about what int **papi[10] is doing and how to use

Comment: @Floyd: Reading C declarations can be a little confusing… Maybe [this](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) helps? `int **papi[10]` would be an array of pointers to pointers to `int`.